# Convert LocalDateTime In any from timezone to any time zone in Java

Tags: java, java-time

- Suppose My `LocalDateTime` in IST i.e. (2020-08-14T15:41)
- Need to convert this IST `LocalDateTime` to any time zone let's say IST to UTC

Required Output : 2020-08-14T10:11 //means 10:11 am
Friday, 14 August 2020

If any `LocalDateTime` from any zone then will get UTC time accordingly UTC time with respect to any time zone time.

**Got a general solution to convert LocalDateTime from any time zone to any time zone** :

```
    LocalDateTime localDateTimeOfFromTimeZone = LocalDateTime.now();//it's takes your default application LocalDateTime
    
    System.out.println("From LocalDateTime : "+localDateTimeOfFromTimeZone);
    
    ZonedDateTime fromTimeZonedDateTime = localDateTimeOfFromTimeZone.atZone(fromTimeZoneId);
    
    LocalDateTime localDateTimeOfToTimeZone = LocalDateTime.from(fromTimeZonedDateTime.withZoneSameInstant(toTimeZoneId));
    
    System.out.println("Converted To LocalDateTime :"+localDateTimeOfToTimeZone);
```

Or

```
    LocalDateTime newDateTime = oldDateTime.atZone(oldZone).withZoneSameInstant(newZone).toLocalDateTime();
```

Comment: [`LocalDateTime.atZone(ZoneId)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#atZone-java.time.ZoneId-) to get a `ZonedDateTime`, then `withZoneSameInstant` to convert to a different zone.

Comment: What have you tried so far and what isn't working? Could you please post that?

Comment: Keep in mind that a `LocalDateTime` does not hold information about a time zone or an offset, it is just year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds and so on. You have to know and pass a `ZoneId` if you want a reliable conversion to UTC.

Comment: Do you know what the time zones are in each case?

Comment: As an alternative, you could use `ZonedDateTime localNow = ZonedDateTime.now()` in the first place, because it will take the `ZoneId.systemDefault()` internally. Afterwards, just do `ZonedDateTime utcNow = localNow.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("UTC"))`...

Answer (score 1):

I recommend against using `LocalDateTime` for at date and time in a time zone. `ZonedDateTime` is the class for that. A `LocalDateTime` is exactly a date and time *without* time zone.

```
    ZoneId fromTimeZoneId = ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata");
    ZoneId toTimeZoneId = ZoneId.of("Etc/UTC");
    
    ZonedDateTime dateTimeOfFromTimeZone = ZonedDateTime.now(fromTimeZoneId);
    System.out.println("From ZonedDateTime:         " + dateTimeOfFromTimeZone);

    ZonedDateTime dateTimeOfToTimeZone
            = dateTimeOfFromTimeZone.withZoneSameInstant(toTimeZoneId);
    System.out.println("Converted To ZonedDateTime: " + dateTimeOfToTimeZone);
```

Output when I ran the code just now:

> ```
> From ZonedDateTime:         2020-08-15T00:13:19.519646+05:30[Asia/Kolkata]
> Converted To ZonedDateTime: 2020-08-14T18:43:19.519646Z[Etc/UTC]
> ```

When using `ZonedDateTime` rather than `LocalDateTime`, Java keeps track of the time zone of each date and time object, which makes it considerably harder to make mistakes in conversions. An advantage that it is hard to overestimate.